# How to use at modules imports (@) in Jest's globalSetup function with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

Using JS hook to invoke TS setupGlobal function (which is using at modules imports, e.g `@app/blablabla.ts`), I'm getting an error `Cannot find module '@config/config'`. I've described `moduleNameMapper` and it's working in tests, but seems it is not in `setupGlobal` function. How can I fix that?

As I wrote, the `moduleNameMapper` is described and Jest can understand those (at modules) imports in tests.

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@tests-suite/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/tests/tests-suite/$1',
    '@config/(.*)': '<rootDir>/config/$1',
    '@tests/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/tests/$1',
    '@src/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
  globalSetup: "<rootDir>/src/tests/unit/jestGlobalSetup.js"
}
```

jestGlobalSetup.js

```
require("ts-node/register");
module.exports = require('./setupTestEnvironment').default;
```

setupTestEnvironment.ts

```js
import { dbConnectionManager } from '@src/dbConnectionManager'

// tslint:disable-next-line:no-default-export
export default async () => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
    setupTestEnvironment()
  }
}

const setupTestEnvironment = async () => {
  await dbConnectionManager.awaitConnection()
}
```

I'm expecting that "at module" imports would be executed in `setupGlobal` function, but it throws the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay. The problem is we were using absolute paths got solved by installing `ts-jest` and adding the next `jest.config.js`:

```
    module.exports = {
  roots: [
    '<rootDir>/src',
  ],
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$',
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'json',
    'jsx',
    'node',
    'ts',
    'tsx',
  ],
  moduleDirectories: [
    'node_modules',
    'src',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@tests\\-suite/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/tests/tests-suite/$1',
    '^@admin/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/admin/$1',
    '^@common/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/common/$1',
    '^@app/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/app/$1',
    '^@partners/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/partners/$1',
    '^@config/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/config/$1',
    '^@tests/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/tests/$1',
    '^@src/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [`<rootDir>/src/tests/setup/GlobalSetup.ts`],
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testMatch: null,
};
```

And our run script looks like this `"test:jest": "NODE_ENV=test yarn ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src/tests/setup/testInit.ts"`

And testInit looks like this;

```
import { runCLI } from 'jest'

// globalSetup
async function init() {
  console.log('Initialization')

  await runCLI({ config: './jest.config.js', watch: true } as any, [__dirname])

  // Do all your initialization stuff
  // I use a setTimeout to simulate true async
  return new Promise<void>((resolve, _reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Init finished')
      resolve()
    }, 1000)
  })
}

// globalTeardown
async function afterTests(): Promise<void> {
  console.log('End of tests - Execute something')
}

init()
  .then(() => {
    afterTests()
  })
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
  .catch(e => console.error(e))
```

GlobalSetup.ts looks like this:

```
import { DBConnectionManager } from '@src/DBConnectionManager'

beforeAll(async () => {
  await DBConnectionManager
  .awaitConnection()
})
```

So the `DBConnectionManager` is just a wrapper around TypeORM, which gives us a connection. It is get connected before each test to hit the real test DB. It works for now.

Comment: I would say this is not the correct solution. I am having the same situation, I cannot find the aliases when I use globalSetup but it works ok with "setupFilesAfterEnv", which is totally different than "globalSetup". setupFilesAfterEnv runs before every test while globalSetup runs only once before all the test. Did you manage to solve this properly?

Comment: @JavierGuzmán nope I didn't. We gave up on that. Have you found a solution?

Comment: More or less...the solution is that unfortunately it's not possible based on the comments on this issue:
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6048